# Restrict object attributes in rails to predefined keys after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to restrict created objects to predefined fields. After i create a user i normally return that object later. But i would like to only return predefined fields. Right now i do it like that.

```
u = User.create(name:"foo", address:"bar", encrypted_password:"secure_pw") 

# render json: u.attributes.except('created_at','updated_at', 'encrypted_password'), status:200
render json: u.attributes.slice('name','address'), status:200
```

But this code is neither DRY nor robust (or pretty;)). How can i write this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `to_json` method in `User` model and use it in controller.

```
def to_json
  {
    name:    name,
    address: address
  }
end
```

Other option would be some (API)Presenter, but seems as overkill to me in this example.

You can also take a look on [ActiveModel::Serializer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).